# Typesetting verse with line numbers directly adjacent (not in margin)

Tags: margins, geometry, line-numbering, verse

When I quote verse (in a document typeset by `XeLaTeX`), I would like to be able to place line numbers directly adjacent to the lines, not in the margin to the left. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,article,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newenvironment{mylinenumbers}{%
    \begin{linenumbers*}\modulolinenumbers[5]}{\end{linenumbers*}%
}

\begin{document}

Now let us consider the opening lines:

\begin{mylinenumbers}
\begin{verse}
Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris\\
Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit\\
litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto\\
vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;\\
multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem,\\
inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,\\
Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.\\
Musa, mihi causas memora, quo numine laeso,\\
quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus\\
insignem pietate virum, tot adire labores\\
impulerit. Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?
\end{verse}
\end{mylinenumbers}
```

The `verse` environment indents the lines of verse, as I would like it to do (since I am quoting it in the midst of a longer document), but then this leaves the line numbers stranded out in the margin, rather than appearing right next to the verse.

How can I place the line numbers just to the left of the lines of verse?

(I should note that I would like the numbers to appear within the body text and not the margin for another reason as well, namely that I am producing a document which must have 1-inch margins in the strict sense that *nothing* may be closer to the edge of the page than 1 inch. Following this constraint will be much easier if I don't have to worry about LaTeX placing anything in the margin.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the separation between line numbers and text by `\setlength\linenumbersep{-8mm}` Adjust the value as suitable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,article,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newenvironment{mylinenumbers}{%
    \setlength\linenumbersep{-8mm}         %% here
    \begin{linenumbers*}\modulolinenumbers[5]}{\end{linenumbers*}%
}


\begin{document}

Now let us consider the opening lines:

\begin{mylinenumbers}
\begin{verse}
Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris\\
Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit\\
litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto\\
vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;\\
multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem,\\
inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,\\
Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.\\
Musa, mihi causas memora, quo numine laeso,\\
quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus\\
insignem pietate virum, tot adire labores\\
impulerit. Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?
\end{verse}
\end{mylinenumbers}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This poem is in Latin. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: That is why I don't understand it. `:-)`

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I was looking for. (It's the beginning of Vergil's *Aeneid*.)

Comment: @AlexRoberts Thanks. egreg already educated me about it. :-)